# Why is my installation searching for the install.php (m1) like so http://example.com/index.php/install/

Tags: installation, nginx, php-7, ee-1.14.2.4

It appears to think it's not in the root directory and searching for it in a area that doesn't exist.

I'm running php 7 with nginx and a standard vagrant vm build. I'm getting the dreaded `404 Not Found nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)`. Of course it's not found because you're looking in the wrong area.

Does this have to do with setting a location for it in my sites-enabled/default.conf???

local.xml

```
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date>{{date}}</date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key>{{key}}</key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[userpw]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[ee]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save>{{session_save}}</session_save>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName>{{admin_frontname}}</frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento Enterprise Edition
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Magento Enterprise Edition End User License Agreement
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_EE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://www.magento.com/license/enterprise-edition
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Core
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2006-2017 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license http://www.magento.com/license/enterprise-edition
 */
-->
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date/>
        </install>
        <resources>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host>localhost</host>
                    <username/>
                    <password/>
                    <dbname>magento</dbname>
                    <model>mysql4</model>
                    <initStatements>SET NAMES utf8</initStatements>
                    <type>pdo_mysql</type>
                    <active>0</active>
                    <persistent>0</persistent>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
            <default_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </default_write>
            <default_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </default_read>
            <core_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mage_Core</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </core_setup>
            <core_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_write</use>
                </connection>
            </core_write>
            <core_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_read</use>
                </connection>
            </core_read>
        </resources>
        <resource>
            <connection>
                <types>
                    <pdo_mysql>
                        <adapter>Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql</adapter>
                        <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Type_Db_Pdo_Mysql</class>
                        <compatibleMode>1</compatibleMode>
                    </pdo_mysql>
                </types>
            </connection>
        </resource>
        <models>
            <varien>
                <class>Varien</class>
            </varien>
            <core>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>core_resource</resourceModel>
            </core>
            <core_resource>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource</class>
                <deprecatedNode>core_mysql4</deprecatedNode>
                <entities>
                    <config_data>
                        <table>core_config_data</table>
                    </config_data>
                    <website>
                        <table>core_website</table>
                    </website>
                    <store>
                        <table>core_store</table>
                    </store>
                    <resource>
                        <table>core_resource</table>
                    </resource>
                    <cache>
                        <table>core_cache</table>
                    </cache>
                    <cache_tag>
                        <table>core_cache_tag</table>
                    </cache_tag>
                    <cache_option>
                        <table>core_cache_option</table>
                    </cache_option>
                </entities>
            </core_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
    <default>
        <system>
            <filesystem>
                <base>{{root_dir}}</base>
                <app>{{root_dir}}/app</app>
                <code>{{app_dir}}/code</code>
                <design>{{app_dir}}/design</design>
                <locale>{{app_dir}}/locale</locale>
                <etc>{{app_dir}}/etc</etc>
                <media>{{root_dir}}/media</media>
                <upload>{{root_dir}}/media/upload</upload>
                <skin>{{root_dir}}/skin</skin>
                <var>{{var_dir}}</var>
                <cache>{{var_dir}}/cache</cache>
                <session>{{var_dir}}/session</session>
                <tmp>{{var_dir}}/tmp</tmp>
                <pear>{{var_dir}}/pear</pear>
                <export>{{var_dir}}/export</export>
            </filesystem>
        </system>
        <dev>
            <template>
                <allow_symlink>0</allow_symlink>
            </template>
        </dev>
        <general>
            <locale>
                <code>en_US</code>
                <timezone>America/Los_Angeles</timezone>
            </locale>
        </general>
    </default>
    <varien>
        <class>Varien</class>
    </varien>
</config>
```

---

sites-available/default

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ cat default 
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    # server_name _;
      server_name 192.168.19.89; 

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

---

nginx.conf

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/etc/nginx$ cat nginx.conf 
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/etc/nginx$
```

Comment: Still looking for some help here if anybody has any ideas.

Comment: do you have your config files in `app/etc/`? if you are missing the `local.xml` or the `config.xml` in that folder magento will think it still needs to be installed.

Comment: @circlesix I've added the files above.

Comment: How about you share your nginx configuration? It's probably an issue with the URL rewrites there. As a reference, here's an  example how it should look like: https://gist.github.com/gwillem/cd5ae6845fa33aa0d481 (also linked in the Magento devdocs)

Comment: @FabianSchmengler I've pasted my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file above.

Comment: @singleton - i'm not a pro with nginx, but your local.xml and config.xml look right, so that's a dead end.

Comment: is your root folder in `/var/www/html` also your magento shop url is IP address, not a domain name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a default nginx configuration for PHP, you need to update it for Magento so that the URL rewrites are working.

Here's a basic one from the old Magento wiki:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
## SSL directives might go here
    server_name www.DOMAIN.com *.DOMAIN.com; ## Domain is here twice so server_name_in_redirect will favour the www
    root /var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN.com;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
    location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex            on;
    }

    location  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
    }
}



    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler

        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;

    }



    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts

        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss



        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;

        fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;

        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores

        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;

        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

    }

}
```

Source: https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/m1wiki/pages/14024849/Configuring+nginx+for+Magento+1.x

And, as mentioned in the comments already, a "battle tested" configuration by Hypernode, which contains many security and performance improvements and is currently also linked in the Magento DevDocs: https://gist.github.com/gwillem/cd5ae6845fa33aa0d481#file-magento-nginx-conf-L77

Comment: There was a few edits i need to make to my sites-available/default file. But for general purposes this got be back on track. What's the purpose of having a nginx.conf file vs sites-enabled/default file. It's kind of redundant in a way, no?